# Lebesgue integral vs area under a curve

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lebesgue measure on Riemann integrable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154537/lebesgue-measure-on-riemann-integrable-function-in-mathbbr2)

Is the Lebesgue integral of a positive real function of a real variable equivalent to the Lebesgue measure of the set (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) of all the points between the interval of integration and the graph of the function?

I'm asking this because all the different definitions of "length", "area", "volume", "measure" I was exposed to (Euclidean geometry, path length, measure of a set, integral, scalar product, ...) seem to be different from one another and I would like to see what are the points in common

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: [dupe?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/154537/8271)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \ge 0$ be measurable. Then (where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$)
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\, dx
     &= \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} \chi_{[0, f(x))}(y)\, dy\, dx\\\
\text{and by the Fubini-Tonelli theorem,}     &\\
     &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} \chi_{[0, f(x))}(y)\, d(x,y)\\
     &= \int_{\mathbb R^2} \chi_{\{(a,b) \mid 0 \le b < f(a)\}}(x,y)\, d(x,y)\\\
     &= \lambda\bigl(\{(x,y) \mid 0 \le y < f(a)\}\bigr).
\end{align*}