# Problem on Product Measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ where  be Lebesgue measurable and $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2:x \in \mathbb R, 0 \le y \le f(x)\}$. How can we show that $S$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and $M_2(S)= \int_{\mathbb R} fdM_1$ where $M_k$ denotes the Lebesgue integral on $\mathbb R^k$ for $k=1,2$. Here $a,b$ is in the extended real line.

I have proved this result using the concept of product measures and Fubini's Theorem. But I want to prove this without getting into product measures.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't type the question as a whole.Don't know what is the problem!

Comment: I have got the entire question typed now.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: $M_2 := M_1\otimes M_1$ by its definition, so how would you like to avoid dealing with product measures?

Comment: @Ilya I was trying to avoid it by using the fact that f can be approximated by simple functions and simple set-theoretic results on cartesian product.

Comment: Well, you know that $\int_\Bbb R f\mathrm dM_1 = \lim_n \int_\Bbb R f_n\mathrm dM_1$ where $f_n\uparrow f$ are simple functions. Thus you only have to show that $M_2(S_n) = \int_\Bbb R f_n\mathrm dM_1 $ (easy), and that $S_n\uparrow S$, then the result follows from the continuity of measures.

Comment: @Ilya Is your $\otimes$ notation that of product measure? in this case you are wrong, because $M_2$ is the *completion* of the product measure of $M_1$ with itself.

Comment: Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/154537/8271)